# Preloading images and setting their dimensions as properties of a class

Tags: javascript, image, class, properties, preload

I want to create a class which will create objects with properties and an image, and also set its properties. I want to keep the ratio of the image, so only width will be passed as argument and height should be set by the class itself.

```
    var scaleFactor = 1;
    class Ships {
      constructor(img, x1, y1, width) {
        let image = new Image();
        image.src = img;
        this.img = image;
        this.x1 = x1 * scaleFactor;
        this.y1 = y1 * scaleFactor;
        this.width = width * scaleFactor;

//I want to set the image height keeping its original ratio

        image.onload = function() {
        this.height  = this.width * image.height / image.width;
        this.x2 = this.x1 + this.width;
        this.y2 = this.y1 + this.height;

//But here 'this' refers to the image element and so it adds the properties to the image element and not the class
        }
        this.draw = function () {
          ctx.drawImage(this.img, this.x1, this.y1, this.width, this.height);
        }
        
      }
    }
```

Is there a way by which I can set the image height and add it as a property to the class?

Comment: Do you mean `this` refers to Image instead of Ships?

Comment: If it is, you can use a variable to save `this` or use an arrow function or function `bind`

Comment: Yeah, I tried using arrow function and it worked. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want the `this` keyword to refer to the image in your onload function, just replace it with an arrow function.  That way, `this` will still refer to the scope outside the function, like so:

```
image.onload = () => {
    this.height  = this.width * image.height / image.width;
    this.x2 = this.x1 + this.width;
    this.y2 = this.y1 + this.height;
}
```